# how to show div for only registered users in html or php not wp

Tags: html, authentication

i'm searched about this question but all i found was about wordpress not for  php or html, my website is based on bootstrap and i want to show a div for onl registered users and give them a message like you must login to view or something like that, is there any way to do that? i can't find topics about it.

i've tried this one:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
// logged in content
} else {
// not logged in content
}
```

but it seems to work only on wordpress, i can't find the php or htm version.

Answer (score 0):

You cant write logical code in HTML only you have to embed  script or logical language with it, its a markup language only. You can achieve it with php as you said but syntax should be like this for if else statement
    `<?php
        if ( $a > $b ) {
              echo "a is greater than b" ;
          } else {
              echo "a is NOT greater than b" ;
        }
       ?>`
You should check in your condition if there is logged in user in session or not.

Comment: i thought it was some code like css visibility hidden but i'm not good in php just a beginner, your code is not working :(

Comment: i did it thanks for your help <pre><?php if(isset($_SESSION['username'])): ?>
<div>logged in content</div>
<?php endif; ?></pre>

Comment: This is just a sample code. It will not work. You can do it with css but for that you have to know where and when to hide and thats a logical part.